# how to generate series of numbers using difference database field

Tags: php, mysql

I have two fields brn_code, acc_type. for example brn_code=7 and acc_type=101..so I want to generate 15 digit account number using branch code and acc_type. for example branch code+acctype+tenzero+one number which generate series like this 710100000000001.

Acc_type may change 101 or 102 and brn_code may change for difference account opened in other branch. so i want to generate series using brn_code+acc_type+tenzero+number increment by one every time new series generated.

this is my code :

```
$J=$_GET['f10']; //brn name
$QRY8 = "SELECT brncode FROM `brn_master` where brnname='$J'";
$RES8 = mysql_query($QRY8);
$R8 = mysql_fetch_array($RES8);
$I=$R8[0];  //BRN CODE
$G=$_GET['f7']; //ACC TYPE
$QRY1 = "SELECT MAX(accno) FROM `account_master` where acc_type='$G'";
$RES1 = mysql_query($QRY1);
$R1 = mysql_fetch_array($RES1);
    IF($R1[0]=='')
    {   
        if($G=="SAVING")
        {
            $n2=101;
            $K="INDIVIDUAL";
            //IND / OTH
        }
        else
        {
            $n2=102;
            $K="OTHERS";   //IND / OTH
        }
        $n1 = $I.$n2;       //110100000000001   
        $new=str_pad("1",11,"0",0);  //sr no generation // 110000100000001
            $newacno=$n1.$new;
        }
        ELSE
        {
            $add = 1;
            $newacno=$R1[0]+$add;
            $conv=sprintf('%.0f',$newacno); //Convert string to number format without decimal
            $newacno=$conv;
        }
```

Please guide how to generate the series using two database fields.

Comment: I wouldn't do that it would be far to easy for someone to enter the wrong account number. I would generate an account number with check digit to mitigate this potential issue.

Comment: Please explain how to generate the account number as per your view..